# SeleniumJava Upcasting and Downcasting

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

For some of my selenium scripts, i need to use JavaScriptExecuter and in order to use this in selenium, i need to declare JavaScriptExecutor js = (JavaScriptExecutor)driver. Kindly advise why i need to pass Webdriver reference above?
Also to better understand this concept, can someone advise what is upcasting and downcasting in JAVA with examples.

Comment: This question is way too broad. There are plenty of examples already on the web. Just google them and read some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java, in order to use method available on any interface/class, the object should be of same class or of class implementing the interface. I would not go into details of java, but for this particular case.
    JavaScriptExecutor js = (JavaScriptExecutor)driver

if we want to use any method available in JavaScriptExecutor interface like executeScript or executeAsyncScript, we will have to cast the driver object to be of JavaScriptExecutor as these methods are not available in WebDriver Interface. So if we have driver defined as :

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); // or any other driver
```

and we want to execute script using this driver. we will first have to cast it into JavaScriptExecutor and then we can call executeScript on it.
If we try to directly call executeScript on driver without casting it to JavaScriptExecutor, it will try to find executeScript method in WebDriver interface and because it is not available in Webdriver, Java compiler will complain